# Horizontal align components inside HBox from Action Script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, hbox, alignment

Is there any way to set horizontalAlign from Action Script not from mxml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center");
```

Comment: Yes, if you check the documentation, anything listed under styles must be set using a call to setStyle() rather than directly as a property.